# iframe shows blank on chrome and firefox but tomcat shows - This content cannot be displayed in a frame

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have some links stored in my database. I am using an iframe to show the link content. Here is my code -

```
dicInformation[temp_1] = a + " " 
+ parts_condition_knowledge[x] + "<p> <iframe src=" 
+ information_link_parts[x] + " height=" +50%+" 
+ width= "+50%+ " + >  </iframe></p>" ;
```

I am using mixture of javascript, html and CSS. When the code runs, the iframe shows: "This content cannot be displayed in a frame" on the tomcat server. When it runs on Chrome and Firefox it shows blank space.

What can be the problem?

Comment: It's probable that the other pages have blocked showing their content inside an iframe. Can you give one of the urls which you are trying to display inside the frame?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U-RfbrnMJZE     - this is one of the url.. there url for google drive, some ramdon information page and etc

Comment: Try it with some very basic websites instead of the really big ones. I'd be curious is if you can get anything to show up. I have a hunch that the sites you're trying to display are getting blocked from

Comment: If you look in your browser console, you can see that youtube is setting a `x-frame-options` header to "sameorigin", which means you can't display their site in an iframe. newyorktimes does this with "deny".

Comment: What do you do with `dicInformation[temp_1]`?

Answer (score 0):

When you trying to access YouTube url it is saying that

> Refused to display 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U-RfbrnMJZE' in a
>   frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

Some sites refused the client to use there site to not to show in iframe. So they have restriction set on their responses.

For more information visit below link.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

There is nothing you can do on your side.

Answer (score 0):

You do not currently show use what you do with `dicInformation` so we cannot really know how the code is going to be used... This being said, you cannot quote and use quotes in JavaScript without escaping the quotes (or mix quotes)

```
dicInformation[temp_1] = a + " "
  + parts_condition_knowledge[x] + "<p> <iframe src=\""
  + information_link_parts[x] + "\" height=\"50%\""
  + " width= \"50%\">  </iframe></p>";
```

Also, because of that, the quotes are missing around the URL and if it includes "invalid" characters (such as an equal sign) you cannot be sure what the browser will do with it.

The "50%" is not valid JavaScript as a numeric. It's okay in a string though as shown in my fixed version.

Mixed quotes would be to use `'` and `"` as required around this and that. For example:

```
 frame = '<iframe href="' + url + '">';
```

This way you avoid having to use the backslash. But I do not personally find that easier to read. To the contrary. Probably more error prone.